# What are some AppKit components used to construct modern Mac document-based apps in 2014?

Tags: cocoa, appkit

I’m risking this question getting closed as “not constructive / argumentative”, as there is no single definitive answer that I’m looking for… but I hope we can make this work. Bear with me.

So. Let’s talk about Mac apps. Cocoa and AppKit are the workhorses on Mac desktop, that can be used to construct classic-looking Mac UI-s. Here’s an example.

[image: iTunes preferences]

The iTunes preferences dialog is a classic-looking Mac UI. Standard toolbar, checkboxes, sliders, separators, buttons. Mac engineers know how to make these, and it’s easy and fun these days with AutoLayout & co.

More recently, though, another style of Mac apps is emerging, that I’d call “modern” apps. In particular, I’m interested in document-based apps, where the document is single-window, decorated with crisp-looking sidebars and other components. Here are two examples (Sketch and Pages).

[image: Sketch]

[image: Pages]

I’m interested in ideas about how these UI-s are constructed, and what kind of components are used. Is AppKit sufficient to achieve this? I read somewhere, but can’t recall the reference, that iWork these days largely forgoes AppKit and the UI just consists of a bunch of hand-drawn CALayers. I’m not so much interested in the document canvas (a whole another subject) as I am in the sidebar, toolbar and their contents.

OK, let’s try to salvage this question with some specific subquestions…

1. General window composition for both apps—is it NSToolbar on top, and NSSplitView in the body area, or something more?
2. Sketch tree view on the left—can I achieve this with NSOutlineView, or is there something more going on?
3. Pages sidebar—what kind of AppKit components are used here, vs custom drawing? (One curious fact that tells me that custom drawing is going on—when I expand/collapse the “Spacing” or “Bullets & Lists” sections, there is no animation.)

Comment: Why would you think you can't use `CALayer` with AppKit or `NSDocument` based apps?

Comment: @jay you absolutely can. It would just be indicative of an interesting direction when Apple tells devs to build UIs with standard components, but then finds the components insufficient for their own apps so they have to resort to lower-lever drawing. (Which is of course always true for bleeding-edge apps to an extent. But still.)

Comment: Well, when it comes to super-fast drawing `CALayer` has been the answer since 10.5 and it's being constantly refined. At this time I can't see why Apple or any other dev should abandon them for something even closer to the metal (at least for standard apps like the ones you've mentioned)

Comment: @jay I don’t mean going closer to the metal, but opposite, to higher layer (AppKit). Sure, with enough investment, anything can be drawn, but I’m wondering how far is it possible to stretch AppKit to achieve such modern look and behavior.

Comment: Not that I want to brag about my own app, but I think it's an example of a native AppKit app that uses a lot of custom controls and drawings. Developing custom controls takes a lot of time, but it sure is a lot of fun! http://cl.ly/image/1p0n3R3D3Z24

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't be fooled by current design choices. IMHO we're building apps the same way we always did it, albeit single window interfaces became more popular in recent years.
But that's just a matter of whether you stuff your `NSView` subclasses in subviews or dedicated windows.
The views themselves shouldn't care at all - in a good application design.

The apps you've mentioned use a mixture of custom and standard controls.

Like apps always did - back to the days of NextStep (or System 7).